# Array in function with global

Tags: php, function

I have one array inside function , this array load all values from csv , for show in website

**The function :**

```
function get_all_values($db_name) {
    $file_db=file("".$db_name."");  
    $exp_table=explode("|","".trim($file_db[0])."");
    for($x=1;$x<sizeof($file_db);$x++) {
        $exp_value=explode("~","".trim($file_db[$x]).""); 
        $j=0;
        foreach($exp_value as $exp_values) {
            ${$exp_table[$j]}[]="".base64_decode($exp_values)."";
            /// this no works ///
            global ${$exp_table[$j]};
            ///
            $j++; 
        }
    }
}
```

I have in this csv one table in the first line , for example :

```
name|phone|direction|email|
```

And the values load after this single table

The function extract the values from csv , and show when i call function , if i don´t use the function and use as no function - only single php code - i can show values putting this for example

```
print $name[0];
print $name[1];
```

The problem it´s when use the function because i need use global var for send out of function all values , and in this case i don´t know how i can use it

Thank´s for the future help and the best regards

Comment: Uh? Why use a GLOBAL??? put all your data inside an array and return the data -.- this way the page that call this function will obtain the result

Comment: Can you put example please , thank´s !!!

Comment: Time to read that PHP book...

Comment: Can you put example of this , and no need read one book , this function create for me and only i wish know his idea , please this places it´s for help no put this things , bye and regards the other user

Comment: comment global ${$exp_table[$j]}; (put // before), the outside the for loop (after the second } before the last } ) put return $exp_value; then in the php page that has get_all_values($db_name) (or similar) put $var = get_all_values($db_name); (or similar) than you can loop on $var and you see all your data